# Mount a Network drive

Tags: mount

I apologize in advance if I missed something simple.
I have an SSD connected to my router as a USB drive and accessible from any device by just entering the UID and PW.
From the RPi I just click Network, and it shows in the list, click again enter credentials and I can navigate on that disk copy, and read.

I would like to permanently mount a folder on the Pi to that drive/subfolder

I am confused when reading the fstab document on GitHub.
I think I should be using cifs when mounting but I do get error messages:-

I have created a sub folder under /mnt called NetworkBackup

The network folder as used below exist on the SMB drive: Z:\RPI_Backups\MQTT_server  (Copied from Windows)

My mount command(UID and PW is fictitious):-

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=tom,password=Pa55word 
 /192.168.1.1/USB_NAS/RPI_Backups/MQTT_server /mnt/NetworkBackup
```

This is the exact string from RPi GUI after connected to the specific folder

```
smb://tp-share/g on tp-share/USB_NAS/RPI_Backups/MQTT_server
```

I then receive the following error:-

```
mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system  
mount error(19): No such device
```

I understand this step is just to confirm the RPi can connect to the shared folder and that the final step will still be o add the line to fstab to make it persistent.

I will really appreciate help with this

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed and configured Samba?

Answer (score 0):

`samba` needs to be installed (and normally password set - I normally use the Pi login password). e.g.

```
sudo apt install samba samba-common-bin smbclient cifs-utils
sudo smbpasswd -a $USER
```

Your mount command seems incorrect. I use:-
`sudo mount.cifs //10.1.2.107/Images /mnt/Image -o user=XXXX`